# border-bottom dotted has solid line at start/end in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

I've created a fiddle to illustrate this: https://jsfiddle.net/9tu8n4y5/

The markup is pretty simple as it's supposed to look like a dotted line to separate bits of content:

```
.dot {
    border-bottom: dotted 2px #022169;
}

<div class="dot"></div>
```

In Firefox 55.0.3 this looks as I'd expect it to:

[image]

However, in Chrome 61.0.3163.91 it has a strange "solid line" at the start and end:

[image]

Closer:

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas why this is? I guess it's a browser specific problem that cannot be changed with CSS?

I am using a 27" 5k Retina iMac. However my second display is a non-Retina screen and the results are the same on that.

Safari 10.0.3 gives the same result as Firefox.

Edit (after posting) - reported to Chromium Bugs team, https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=766977

Comment: Yes, It's a browser specific problem. If you used 4px border then problem is solved.

Comment: Ok, but obviously that changes the size of the dots... which isn't what I want. I don't want to use something at 4px when I want 2px... that's not a solution.

Comment: Yes, I know that's not solution but I am only explain it.

Comment: Ok, thank you anyway. Incidentally it doesn't work at 3px either.

Comment: If you want to use image then i have a solution.

Comment: I want to use CSS. No images, but thanks.

Comment: [Useful workaround would be to use a gradient like this example.](https://jsfiddle.net/m4nLtez1/) Adapted from the Codepen here: [https://codepen.io/terkel/pen/JiFgs](https://jsfiddle.net/m4nLtez1/)

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tested this solution on retina, but you can play around with radius values to get exactly/closer to what you want. This is how I have dealt with the bug:

```css
.border-bug {
  border-bottom: 2px dotted red;
}

.no-border-bug {
   border-bottom: 2px dotted red;
   border-left: 2px solid transparent;
   border-top: 1px solid transparent;
   border-radius: 4px 1px 3px 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="border-bug">
Bug Bug Bug.
</div>
<br>
<div class="no-border-bug">
Almost no bug.
</div>
```

This bug seems like have been around since ages.

Comment: Thanks. I've reported it to the Chromium bugs tracker and someone is looking into it; it's been like that for a long time. I've tested your solution on a Retina display and it looks ok but is "missing" some of the left/right border. It's really a browser bug that Google will have to sort out - I don't think there is any CSS or front-end code that can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Just found a work around: add Css Property `border-collapse: separate;` to table and it will work fine.

Comment: If you use a backtick around the word you can format the entries as code

Comment: Okay Thanks I would do that